# Keeping reference to object when creating a closure and storing it

Tags: swift, closures, capture-list

I have a question about how references to objects are handled in closures in specific example. The code below is simplified to demonstrate the idea

```
class SomeObject {
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
    var value: Int {
        didSet {
            valueObservers.forEach { $0(value) }
        }
    }
    var valueObservers = [(Int) -> Void]()
}

class TestClass {

    let obj1 = SomeObject(value: 1)
    let obj2 = SomeObject(value: 2)
    let obj3 = SomeObject(value: 3)

    func valueOfObjectChanged(object: SomeObject) {
        print("Value of object \(object) is \(object.value)")
    }

    init() {
        let objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
        objects.forEach { (object) in
            object.valueObservers.append { [unowned self] (_) in
                self.valueOfObjectChanged(object: object)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So we have here a class `SomeObject` which can store an array of closures which will be executed when value of its variable changes. `TestClass` creates a few of these objects, then makes array from this objects, and for every object in this array it adds a closure that will execute a function of `TestClass` when a value of any of these `SomeObjects` changes.

OK now inside this function that can be triggered by any of created objects, I want to be sure that I know which object did actually caused it to execute. The reference is passed in function execution, but note that `object` here is get from a loop and passed to the closure (closure which will execute valueOfObjectChanged and pass object reference as parameter).

What's the problem with that - I'm not sure if the reference to object will actually be kept for correct object, as this closure is executed somewhere completely different then when the closure was created.

I can't put `object` in this closure `capture list`, because this causes `Segmentation fault: 11`.

I'm not sure how the closure would behave in this situation - will reference to object be kept, or can it be wrong?

I could also add the caller in definition of `valueObservers`, but this is something I would like to avoid because of current structure of the app (the example is just a simplification).

So my question is - is the reference to `object` under `object.valueObservers.append` always correct, and points to the object, that changed it's value, or is it incorrect, and for example points to the last object that was iterated in `objects.forEach` or even something else?

Comment: `for example points to the last object that was iterated` - e.g. like in javascript? :)

Comment: Note that you created a retain cycle, as `object` gets strongly captured by the closure, and the closure is strongly captured by `object`.

Comment: You are right there was a retain cycle, and the other thing is that now actually I can add object and `unowned object` in the closure capture list. Don't know why I was getting Segmentation fault before, maybe some temporary error. Anyway it's working like expected now.